# Access Request from a nested service

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is there an easy way to access the Request object from a nested service call?

**For example:**

```
// Entry Point
public class ServiceA : Service
{
    public AResponse Get(ARequest request)
    {
        // Request is ok in entry point.

        // Now call another service
        var srvResp = TryResolve<ServiceB>().Get(new BRequest{ ... });
    }
}

// Called through Service A
ServiceB : Service
{   
    public BResponse Get(BRequest request)
    {
        // Request is not set here (null).
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ResolveService<T>` method provided by the `Service` class to resolve the service. This will make the `Request` object available to the service you are resolving.

```cs
public class ServiceA : Service
{
    public AResponse Get(ARequest request)
    {
        // Request is ok in entry point.

        // Use ResolveService<T> here not TryResolve<T>
        var srvResp = ResolveService<ServiceB>().Get(new BRequest{ ... });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Argh.  I knew that one too.  Too much time between projects.  Thanks!